# When I run my react app after build, nothing gets displayed on the html page. How do I resolve this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, content-security-policy

I am working on a react/express project. I have generated my `npm build` folder, but when I try to run it in my html browser, the favicon changes, besides that, nothing else displays.

```
app.use(globalErrorHandler);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "public", "build", "index.html"))
  );
}
```

Is there something i'm missing?

I am getting this error on the console

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-81wjRQUIesSdM31ZewxoTpdk1zPOVbB5yDbEGkTCGjE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use Helmet 4 middleware, it publishes a [default Content Security Policy](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/wiki/Helmet-4-upgrade-guide#there-is-now-a-default-policy).

Switch it off for a while or tune CSP rules to allow inline scripts (`<script>... </script>` construct).